# Toggle visibility of local QWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a modal QDialog which has several widgets in it arranged in a grid layout. It has a radio button group which should toggle visibility on some of the widgets if a certain button is pressed. This QDialog is declared locally. I'm having trouble accessing the widgets through the connected buttonClicked() function. Is there a way to accomplish this without passing all of the widgets into the function or making them part of the base class?

```
def optionsdlg(self):               
    self.oWin = QDialog()
    self.oWin.setModal(True)
    self.oWin.setWindowTitle("Options")

    layout = QGridLayout()

    Button1 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Button1")
    Button2 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Button2")
    Button3 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Button3")
    lcbg = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
    lcbg.addButton(Button1, 0)
    lcbg.addButton(Button2, 1)
    lcbg.addButton(Button3, 2)
    lcbg.buttonClicked.connect(updateType(lcbg.checkedId()))
    scalingLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Scaling:")
    scalingLabel.setVisible(False)                              
    scalingLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(str(self.scaling))
    scalingLineEdit.setVisible(False)
    offsetLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Offset:")
    offsetLabel.setVisible(False)
    offsetLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(str(self.offset))
    offsetLineEdit.setVisible(False)

    self.oWin.setLayout(layout)

    self.oWin.exec_()

    def updateType(button):            
        if button == 0:
        elif button == 1:
        elif button == 2:
            scalingLabel.setVisible(True)
            scalingLineEdit.setVisible(True)
            offsetLabel.setVisible(True)
            offsetLineEdit.setVisible(True)
```

Comment: I don't see how your code will even work, since you're calling `updateType` before it's defined.  (Is your indentation correct there, that is, is `updateType` defined inside `optionsdlg`?)

Comment: The following line is incorrect `buttonClicked.connect(updateType(lcbg.checkedId()))`. Also you comment that each button manages the visibility of some widgets, and I see in your function you make them visible to all.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. For brevity's sake I omitted the widgets that don't require visibility changes. I've tried defining the updateType function immediately within the parent function and also outside it. When I define it inside and immediately I'm met with "TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'". To my understanding I will be outside of the scope of the QDialog/layout/widgets if I define it outside.

Comment: @98yearoldrefridgerator see my answer.